# raise ScannerError(None, None, yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: python, yaml

I'm attempting to become more familiar with Python's .yaml file format. I chose a basic toy and began playing with it. However, I initially encountered one problem. I searched for a solution and attempted several examples available on Google but could not succeed.
**Here is my code**

**test.yaml**

[image]

**and here is my main.py**

```
    import yaml
if __name__ == '__main__':

    stream = open("test.yaml", 'r')
    dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print (key + " : " + str(value))
```

**Error**

```
"C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Code_Playing_Testing/main.py"
C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Code_Playing_Testing/main.py:10: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Code_Playing_Testing/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 223, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 577, in fetch_value
    raise ScannerError(None, None,
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "test.yaml", line 2, column 10
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a YAML mapping, every key has exactly one value. The key `foo` cannot have both the scalar `bar` *and* the nested mapping starting with `pleh:` as value.

It is unclear what you are trying to do, but any of the following will work:

```yaml
# dropping the value `bar`
foo:
  pleh: help
  stuff:
    foo: bar
    bar: foo
```

```yaml
# making `bar` a value of the nested mapping
foo:
  name: bar
  pleh: help
  stuff:
    foo: bar
    bar: foo
```

```yaml
# assuming `bar` and `pleh` should be a single multiline value.
# this requires the explicit key marker `?`.
foo:
  ? bar
    pleh
  : help
  stuff:
    foo: bar
    bar: foo
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got this example from this link = https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started.

Comment: @Ahmad That tutorial is full of indentation errors. I recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Thanks alot, would you please share any authentic source for python programing

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry, I don't curate Python YAML tutorials and that is also not StackOverflow's purpose. But why don't you start at the [official documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#tutorial)?